# PDO and defined constants .. php error

Tags: php

I have set constants for database in connect.php.

connect.php

```
define('DB_HOST','localhost');
define('DB_NAME','dbname');
define('DB_USER','dbuser');
define('DB_PASSWORD','dbpass');
```

Here is the Database Class

```
require("connect.php");
    class Database {

    private $connect;

    function opendb() {
    $this->connect = new PDO(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);

    }


    function closedb() {
    $this->connect =  null; //close connection

    }

    }
```

I get this error when i load the page that accesses the database class.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'invalid data source name'
```

what did i do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this -

```
$this->connect = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to give the connection string here instead of the constant DB_NAME:

```
 $this->connect = new PDO(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

like

```
 $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname='.DB_NAME;
 $this->connect = new PDO(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD);
```

**EDIT**

you should also use the HOST constant as its defined.

```
 $dsn = 'mysql:host='.DB_HOST.';dbname='.DB_NAME;
```